# How can I dynamically create a checkerboard using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what I have so far the rules are that I can't hardcode anything, I cant touch the HTML, and I have to append my whole array at once to get the result. I'm basically having trouble pushing 8 `<td>` to my 8 `<tr>`. Thanks for the help.

JavaScript

```js
var checkerBoard = [];
$(function(){


  for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){

    var trOdd = $('<tr>').addClass('odd');
    var trEven = $('<tr>').addClass('even');

    if(i % 2 !== 0){ checkerBoard.push(trEven); }
    else { checkerBoard.push(trOdd); }

    for(var j = 0; j < checkerBoard.length; j++){
      checkerBoard[j].append('<td>');
    }
}

  $('tbody').append(checkerBoard);
  $( ".odd td:odd" ).css( "background-color", "white" );
  $( ".odd td:even" ).css( "background-color", "black" );
  $( ".even td:odd" ).css( "background-color", "black" );
  $( ".even td:even" ).css( "background-color", "white" );

  $('#gameBoard').css({
    'border-collapse' : 'collapse',
    'border' : 'solid 1px black'
  });

  $('td').css({
    'width'  : '30px',
    'height' : '30px'
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h1> Game Board </h1>
<table id="gameBoard">
<tbody></tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 8 cells per row too ... those have nothing to do with checkerboard array length when run inside first loop because checkerboard array length hasn't been completed yet

change :

```
for(var j = 0; j < checkerBoard.length; j++){
  checkerBoard[j].append('<td>');
}
```

To

```
for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    checkerBoard[i].append('<td>');
}
```

Also note all the styles you are adding with script could easily be done in css without script

```js
var checkerBoard = [];
$(function(){


  for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){

    var trOdd = $('<tr>').addClass('odd');
    var trEven = $('<tr>').addClass('even');

    if(i % 2 !== 0){ checkerBoard.push(trEven); }
    else { checkerBoard.push(trOdd); }

    for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
      checkerBoard[i].append('<td>');
    }
}

  $('tbody').append(checkerBoard);
  $( ".odd td:odd" ).css( "background-color", "white" );
  $( ".odd td:even" ).css( "background-color", "black" );
  $( ".even td:odd" ).css( "background-color", "black" );
  $( ".even td:even" ).css( "background-color", "white" );

  $('#gameBoard').css({
    'border-collapse' : 'collapse',
    'border' : 'solid 1px black'
  });

  $('td').css({
    'width'  : '30px',
    'height' : '30px'
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h1> Game Board </h1>
<table id="gameBoard">
<tbody></tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Man I feel stupid. I had changed checkerBoard.length to 8 already but I had forgot to change checkerBoard[j] to checkerBoard[i]. Yea I know it was just part of the challenge to do it with jquery. Thanks for the help I appreciate it. I was working on this problem for a while already, I was getting frustrated.

Comment: hey...we all have our moments staring at things that seem so right and kick ourselves for not noticing why it's not working right

Comment: I would also make a small change while setting the css. Set the table background to white and fill black in required cells.

    `$('tbody').append(checkerBoard);
    $("table").css( "background-color", "white" );
    $( "tr.odd td:even" ).css( "background-color", "black" );
    $( "tr.even td:odd" ).css( "background-color", "black" );`

Answer (score 1):

You could use simple array concatenation to generate the html content

```js
var checkerBoard = [];
$(function() {

  var row = new Array(9).join('<td></td>');
  var body = new Array(9).join('<tr>' + row + '</tr>');
  var $tbody = $('#gameBoard tbody').html(body);

  $tbody.find('tr:odd').addClass('odd');
  $tbody.find('tr:even').addClass('even');

  $tbody.find('tr:odd td:odd').addClass('white');
  $tbody.find('tr:odd td:even').addClass('black');
  $tbody.find('tr:even td:odd').addClass('black');
  $tbody.find('tr:even td:even').addClass('white');


  $('#gameBoard').css({
    'border-collapse': 'collapse',
    'border': 'solid 1px black'
  });

  $('td').css({
    'width': '30px',
    'height': '30px'
  });

});
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <h1> Game Board </h1>
  <table id="gameBoard">
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```

---

But you can use a simple css solution also like

```js
$(function() {

  var row = new Array(9).join('<td></td>');
  var body = new Array(9).join('<tr>' + row + '</tr>');
  $('#gameBoard tbody').html(body);

});
```

```css
#gameBoard {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
#gameBoard td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
#gameBoard tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: black;
}
#gameBoard tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n +1) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <h1> Game Board </h1>
  <table id="gameBoard">
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```